# how to covert a .csv file into a list of lists in Common-Lisp

Tags: csv, common-lisp, clisp

I am new to common-lisp and wanted to know how to convert a .csv file to a 2d list.
I see that we can read the .csv file using:

```
(cl-csv:read-csv #P"filename.csv")
```

and you can convert into a 2d array by:

```
(defun read-2d-array (rows &rest args)
  (let* ((first-line (apply #'read-line args))
         (cols (1+ (count #\space first-line)))
         (arr (make-array (list rows cols)
                          :element-type 'integer
                          :initial-element 0)))
    (loop for i below rows
          for line = first-line then (apply #'read-line args)
          for start = 0
          do (dotimes (j cols)
               (multiple-value-bind (number end)
                   (parse-integer line :start start
                                       :junk-allowed t)
                 (setf start end
                       (aref arr i j) number))))
    arr))
```

but my output looks like this after the above one:

*#(#\c #\o #\l #\u #\m #\n #_ #\n #\a #\m #\e #, #\w #\i #\d #\t #\h #, #\l
#\e #\n #\g #\t #\h #, #\v #\e #\r #\t #\i #\c #\a #\l #_ #\r #/ #\f #,
#\s #\t #\i #\r #\r #\u #\p #\Return #\Newline #\c #\1 #, #\9 #, #\1 #\2
#, #" #\4 #- #\1 #\2 #\d #\i #\a #, #\4 #- #\1 #\0 #\d #\i #\a #" #,
#\8 #- #\1 #\5 #\0 #\c #/ #\c #\Return #\Newline*

but i want it to look something like :
`((column_name width length vertical_r/f stirrup) (c1 9 12 4-12dia 8-150c/c))`

Can someone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The language is called Common Lisp (short CL). CLISP is an implementation written in C and CL.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I have made the changes. Thanks on the info.

Comment: do you really want a list of symbols? or Strings?

Comment: What do you actually want the return value to be?  `(read-csv #P"file.csv")` *does* return a nested list of entries from the lines in the file.

Comment: @ignisvolens But the output looks like ```#(#\c #\o #\l #\u #\m #\n #\  #\n #\a #\m #\e #\, #\w #\i #\d #\t #\h #\, #\l
  #\e #\n #\g #\t #\h #\, #\v #\e #\r #\t #\i #\c #\a #\l #\  #\r #\/ #\f #\,
  #\s #\t #\i #\r #\r #\u #\p #\Return #\Newline```
I don't want the #\, just as strings

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes a list of strings, why what other alternative would you suggest?

Comment: In your example you have a list of symbols.

Comment: @Gayathri: the return value of `read-csv` does *not* look like that.  Why not just call it?  You will get back a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file, `/tmp/x.csv` containing

```
column_name,width,length,vertical_r/f,stirrup
c1,9,12,4-12dia,8-150c/c
```

then using [cl-csv](https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv):

```
> (read-csv #p"/tmp/x.csv")
(("column_name" "width" "length" "vertical_r/f" "stirrup")
 ("c1" "9" "12" "4-12dia" "8-150c/c"))
```